# python - making an additional (parasite axis) next to the primary x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the below example which shows construction of an additional axis next to the y-axis.
https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html

[image]

What I wanted to know is how do I amend codes to get another parasite axis at the bottom next to the primary x-axis, such that it is tied directly to the primary y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the sample in the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axisartist/demo_parasite_axes2.html) to achieve your goal. This is achieved by adjusting the offset position and the range of the y-axis. Does this meet the intent of your question?

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
from mpl_toolkits import axisartist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=axisartist.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

par1 = host.twiny()
par2 = host.twiny()

par2.axis["bottom"] = par2.new_fixed_axis(loc="bottom", offset=(0, 25))

par1.axis["top"].toggle(all=True)
par2.axis["bottom"].toggle(all=True)

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
p2, = par1.plot([0, 3, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Temperature")
p3, = par2.plot([50, 30, 15], [0, 1, 2], label="Velocity")

host.set_ylim(-0.25, 2)
host.set_xlim(0, 2)
par1.set_xlim(0, 4)
par2.set_xlim(1, 65)

host.set_xlabel("Distance")
host.set_ylabel("Density")
par1.set_xlabel("Temperature")
par2.set_xlabel("Velocity")

host.legend()

host.axis["bottom"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.axis["top"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())
par2.axis["bottom"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @r-beginners, I was thinking more in the direction of having a parasite axis below the primary x-axis "in addition" to the existing parasite axis next to the primary y-axis shown in the reference example. So in short there will be two parasite axis. Is that possible?

Comment: I think it is possible by adding the code part modified in my answer to the example given in the sample.